# Node.js process.versions.node is Undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using a react library that is trying to access process.versions.node. This value is empty when I log it to the console. I've tried removing and reinstalling node.js (using the [installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)). I'm on node version v14.15.0 on macOS 10.15.7.

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

The code line in question:

```
const nodeMajor = Number(process.versions.node.split('.')[0])
```

When I log this I get undefined:

```
console.log(process.versions.node)
//undefined
```

Why would this value be undefined and how can I fix it?

Comment: `node -p 'process.versions'` shows me an object including a `node` props as expected, currently Node 12.18.3 via NVM on macOS.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not access `process` in your browser (just an assumption, since you use React). Do you use Webpack or anything else?

Comment: I see a process.versions.node at the terminal. However, it's never set in the node module. I'm console logging from inside the node module. I can log process in react and it does have values but the version property is empty.

Comment: Running Node and issuing `const nodeMajor = Number(process.versions.node.split('.')[0])` works just fine, and console logging `nodeMajor` says 14 when using v14.x, so you're going to have to be more explicit: how are you running that code? (on a JS note, rather than the `Number` object type, instead use `parseInt(...)` or `parseFloat(...)` to turn strings into numbers)

Comment: I'm using a react library and trying to debug it. I filed a GitHub issue with the project but now I believe it's something with my node environment. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1345

Comment: If I set nodeMajor to a valid integer everything works fine.

Comment: I don't think this node library wasn't really designed to run in the browser. So that value is null because the code is being executed client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I was using this component within a react.js application. Since react.js is rendered in the browser, it makes sense that there is no node.js version information.